# ZeroDivsionError with factorial in python

Tags: python

I get a zero when I'm running the code

factorial(n-x)*factorial(x)

It's my first time asking on stackoverflow.

below are my codes

```
def factorial(x):
    res = 1

    if x==0:
        return 1
    
    while x>0:
        res*=x
        x-=1
    return res

def combination(n,x):
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(n-x)*factorial(x))

def binomial(n,x,p):
    return combination(n,x)*(p**x)*((1-p)**(n-x))

pmf_values = []

n=200
x_list = np.arange(0,200+1)

for x in x_list:
    #print(x)
    #print((factorial(n-x)*factorial(x)))
    pmf_values.append(binomial(n,x,p))

sample = np.random.choice(
    x_list,size=10000,p=pmf_values)
plt.hist(sample)
```

I found that the error occurs when x is 0.
when I run it in a seperate cell,
it returns the correct answer 1.0

It's strange that it works fine in a seperate cell
but returns an error in a loop

Thank you for helping

Comment: What does "run it in a seperate cell" mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is actually quite well structured, but your code is not replicable. Please don't simply copy paste your existing code, but instead, start from scratch and build a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that other people can run with no issue.

Comment: In `pmf_values.append(binomial(n,x,p))`, `p` is undefined.

Comment: A couple comments about `factorial`:  (1) The special case for `x == 0` is completely unnecessary.  Just delete it.  The `while` loop will be skipped when `x` is zero, and you'll fall through and return `1` as intended.  Don't invent unnecessary special cases.  And (2) You don't need your own factorial.  You can just use `math.factorial.`  Also, if your Python version is 3.8 or later, you can use `math.comb` in place of `combination`.

Comment: thank you everyone, I'll post my question more clearly and make my code replicable next time. I think it wasn't a good idea to make function from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got zeroes using your factorial function. This is strange. (Python 3.10.10).

I printed outputs:

```
factorial(135)*factorial(65)
0*-9223372036854775808=0
factorial(134)*factorial(66)
0*0=0
...
factorial(66)*factorial(134)
0*0=0
factorial(65)*factorial(135)
-9223372036854775808*0=0
...
factorial(23)*factorial(177)
8128291617894825984*0=0
factorial(22)*factorial(178)
-1250660718674968576*0=0
factorial(21)*factorial(179)
-4249290049419214848*0=0
factorial(20)*factorial(180)
2432902008176640000*0=0
```

The return of the factorial began to oscillate negative/positive above factorial(20), and went to zero beginning at factorial(66)

Try this, this worked for me and looks nicer anyway:

```
def factorial(x):
  res = 1 
  for i in range(2,x+1):
    res *= i
  return res
```

***Edit:***

I got it to work using your original factorial function:

```
def factorial(x):
  x = int(x)
  res = 1
  while x > 1:
    res *= x
    x -= 1
  return res
```

So, this is an overflow issue with numpy. The x being passed in comes from np.arange()

The reason my shorter function worked is because there is never math between numpy int64s, and if you convert x into a Python int before you do the math it will also work. Otherwise, the numpy int64 type will overflow

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors

```
$ pip freeze | grep numpy
numpy==1.24.3
```

Comment: thank you very much for your kind answer. I wasn't familiar with numpy, your answer helped me a lot